# Problem on Mann Whitney U test statistic

Tags: normal-distribution, hypothesis-testing

Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_m \sim N(\mu_1, \Sigma)$ and $Y_1, Y_2, \ldots, Y_n \sim N(\mu_2, \Sigma)$.

(Here, $\Sigma$ is the variance-covariance matrix of the 2 multivariate Normal distributions stated above; $X_1, \ldots, X_m, Y_1, \ldots, Y_n, \mu_1 \; \textrm{and} \; \mu_2$ - all being vectors.)

Now for some $\alpha$ (which is a vector), we compute : $$\alpha^{'}X_1, \alpha^{'}X_2, \ldots, \alpha^{'}X_m$$ and $$\alpha^{'}Y_1, \alpha^{'}Y_2, \ldots, \alpha^{'}Y_n.$$

Now, this means that $\alpha^{'}X_1, \alpha^{'}X_2, \ldots, \alpha^{'}X_m \sim N(\alpha^{'}\mu_1, \alpha^{'}\Sigma\alpha)$.

Similarly, $\alpha^{'}Y_1, \alpha^{'}Y_2, \ldots, \alpha^{'}Y_n \sim N(\alpha^{'}\mu_2, \alpha^{'}\Sigma\alpha)$.

Now, my null hypothesis is $H_0 : \alpha^{'}\mu_1 = \alpha^{'}\mu_2$ versus the alternative hypothesis $H_1 : \alpha^{'}\mu_1 > \alpha^{'}\mu_2$.

My question is : how do I prove that the power function of the one-sided Mann Whitney U Test will be maximum when $\alpha \propto \Sigma^{-\frac{1}{2}} (\mu_1 - \mu_2)$ ?

Comment: Please look at my edit to the question.  What I got rid of is not proper MathJax usage. $\qquad$

Comment: Very good question. Letting $\nu=\mu_1-\mu_2$, one seeks the vector $\alpha\in\mathbb R^{k\times 1}$ that maximizes the quantity $\dfrac{\alpha'\nu}{\sqrt{\alpha'\Sigma\alpha}}$, where $\Sigma \in \mathbb R^{k\times k}$ is positive-definite, and the question is what the maximizing value is $\alpha = \Sigma^{-1/2} \nu$. Some statistics questions posted here can be expected to go over the heads of mathematicians qua mathematicians, but this one is just math and fits math(dot)stackexchange(dot)com very well. $\qquad$